# Exception: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured

Tags: c#, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to connect to AWS DynamoDb by creating an `AmazonDynamoDBClient`.

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Amazon.Runtime.AmazonClientException: No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured
at Amazon.Runtime.ClientConfig.Validate()
at Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceClient..ctor(AWSCredentials credentials, ClientConfig config)
```

I have the following lines in my ***App.Config*** file (the actual keys are in my code):

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="AWSProfileName" value="development" />
    <add key="AWSAccessKey" value="XXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="AWSSecretKey" value="YYYYYYYYYY" />
    <add key="AWSRegion" value="us-east-2" />
  </appSettings>
```

I also have a ***credentials*** file under the ***AWS*** folder. Includes the following:

```
[development]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYYYY
```

In my code, I'm simply calling to:

```
AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
```

I'm working in visual-studio 2019. This used to work when I was working in a simple console application environment. Now I am working under Azure-Functions template project.
Why am I getting error?

Comment: The credentials file will take precedent, that's why. Add the region to the file as well using `region = us-east-2` or alternatively, remove your credentials file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is not working since you have added AWSRegion to the config. I suggest to add the below to your credentials file

```
[development]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = YYYYYYYYYY
region = us-east-2
```